# Find the users pointing to my database postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql

I logged into the `psql` console to delete some databases, but it gives me this error:

> ERROR:  database "production" is being accessed by other users DETAIL:
>   There is 1 other session using the database.

How should I find the users pointing to my database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pg_stat_activity` view. It will show pretty much everything that is of interest about every open session, such as the user (`usename`), where s/he is connecting from (`client_addr` and `client_hostname`), the `state` (active, idle, etc) and the last `query` (being) executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from `pg_user` table

```
SELECT * FROM pg_user;
```

Or from [`pg_stat_activity`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/monitoring-stats.html) view

```
SELECT usesysid, usename FROM pg_stat_activity;
```